# Is there a way to speed up some data prossecing?

Tags: python, performance

I have a big table of data (something like 3100000 lines and 6 col) and I want to extract some subset of data and rearrange them.

I tried this code:

```
tab=[]
tab.append(np.array(['Channel', 'Edge', 'Time', 'Sweep', 'Tag', 'DataLost']))
incl=[]
incl.append(np.array(['Mult', 'x1', 'x2', 'y1', 'y2']))

for i in range (0,max):
B=tab[tab[:,3]==str(i),:]
C1=B[B[:,0]==str(Voie_Stop_1),2]
C2=B[B[:,0]==str(Voie_Stop_2),2]
if len(C1)%2 ==0 and len(C2)%2 ==0 and len(C1) ==len(C2) :
    nb_fragments=len(C1)/2 
    C1=C1.reshape(int(nb_fragments), 2)
    C2=C2.reshape(int(nb_fragments), 2)
    C1C2=np.concatenate((C1,C2), axis=1)
    ligne=np.insert(C1C2, 0, nb_fragments,axis=1)
    ligne=np.array(ligne)
    for j in range(int(nb_fragments)):
        incl.append(ligne[j])
        ligne=C1C2[0]
        unSTOP.append(ligne)
```

It is doing what I want but is is extremely slow (5s to make i+100)... To fill my tabs, I use the function "append" because someone on this forum tells me that it is faster than "concatenate" and indeed it is true in the first part of my code (not shown here)... Could you help me .... ??? (I'm quite new in python...)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the fastest way to manipulate large datasets in Python is to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).  In pandas, you import your data into a table-like structure called a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). You can then can perform operations on the data quickly using the API.

Depending on how your data is stored (csv, python dictionary, sql, etc.) you can pull the data into memory quickly and easily using the [pandas IO methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/my/data.csv')
```

`df` is your dataframe.  You can then [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), [apply custom functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), and more very quickly.

If you can post a sample of your data and some information about how specifically you would like to extract and re-arrange the data, I'd be happy to write an example function for you to help get the job done.